# ng-click child checkbox of Parent div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-change

How do you make a parent div click propagate to its child checkbox in AngularJS?  The Checkbox will have the `hidden` attribute, so we need to allow the parent div be the clickable entity.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="checkboxApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <form name="myForm">
        Value1:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" /><br />
        Value2:<input type="checkbox" value="value-2" ng-model="value2" ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO" /><br />
        <tt>value1 = {{value1}}</tt><br />
        <tt>value2 = {{value2}}</tt><br />

        <hr />

        <div class="btn btn-primary">
          Value1 (hidden):<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" hidden/><br />
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary" >
          Value2:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value2" ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO" /><br />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('checkboxApp', []);

angular.module('checkboxApp')
  .controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function MainController($scope){
    $scope.value1 = true;
    $scope.value2 = 'YES'
  }]);
```

Plnkr: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WuYbZuw1NGVSiX23mHUP?p=preview)

I have tried a click function() as well on the ng-change, but I still can't get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add an ng-click onto the parent div like this. This example would work if you did not use ng-true-value and ng-false-value.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="value1 = !value1>
  Value1 (hidden):<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" hidden/><br />
</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="value2 = !value2>
  Value2:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value2"/><br />
</div>
```

Otherwise just use a function: ng-click="toggle(value2)"

```
$scope.toggle = function(val) {
    if (val === "YES") {
        val = "NO";
    } else {
        val = "YES";
    }
}
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GocUv6L3xxi85xIfd9JE?p=preview)

Comment: hrm...  I tried that earlier and it said that I needed a `ng-model`....   can't get it to reproduce it, so maybe I had a syntax error when I tried moving the click to the parent div.

Comment: @Zack Argyle, this has an issue with when the user click the checkbox itself. That'll trigger a click on the parent div, and the checkbox value will remain the same.